# Kendo-Angular 2 UI Numeric Text Box change event not fired

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using Angular 2 and i need to use Numeric Text Box. Since Kendo Numeric Text Box for Angular 2 is not released yet, so I have to use Kendo Numeric TextBox with Javascript. However, the change event is not fired when value in text box is changed. 
Also, the Kendo Progress Bar does not show animation as it should. Could somebody please help?

Thank you

product-details.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from '../shared/services/toastr.service';
import { UserService } from '../shared/services/user.service';
import { SystemAccessEnum } from '../shared/services/systemAccessEnum';

import { ProductService } from './services/product.service';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'product-details',
    templateUrl: 'app/products/product-details.component.html',

})

export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() product: any;


    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private toastrSvc: ToastrService, private userSvc: UserService, private systemAccessEnum: SystemAccessEnum, private productSvc: ProductService) {

    }


    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        var element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        var ieerRatingBar = jQuery(element).find(".ieerRatingBar");
        if (ieerRatingBar[0] != undefined &&       this.product.specifications.all.ieerNonducted) {
            jQuery(ieerRatingBar[0]).kendoProgressBar({
                animation: {
                    duration: 600
                },

                showStatus: false,
                max: 40,
                value: this.product.specifications.all.ieerNonducted.value
            });
        }




        //numeric stepper
        var numericTextBox = jQuery(element).find(".numericTextBox");
        if (numericTextBox[0] != undefined) {
            jQuery(numericTextBox[0]).kendoNumericTextBox({
                change: function () {
                    var value = this.value();
                    debugger
                    this.product.quantity = value;
                }

            });
        }

    }


};
```

product-details.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-2 product-image"><img width="135" height="100" src="{{product.image.url}}" /></div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 product-info">
        <div class="row">{{product.name}}</div>
        <div class="row">Model No.: {{product.productNumber}}</div>
        <div class="row">Price: {{product.price | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-md-5" *ngIf="product.specifications.all != null">

        <div class="row" *ngIf="product.specifications.all.ieerNonducted">IEER (Non-Ducted): {{product.specifications.all.ieerNonducted.value | number:'1.2-2'}}</div>
        <div class="ieerRatingBar"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-1">
        <input class="numericTextBox" type="number" value="{{product.quantity}}" min="0" max="1000" step="1" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
</div>
```